# mysql doesn't start from the control panel

Tags: php, xampp

hi i recently installed xampp 1.7.0 , but when i try to start the mysql from the control panel it gives error:

Busy....
ERROR: Mysql service not started [-1]

and

when i start from the mysql_start.bat it starts !!

why is this happening why mysql is not starting from xampp control pannel?

Answer (score 2):

Not certain of your install but often there are related services necessary to the running that the control panel is not initializing first.

Installing FoxServ (similar to Xamp) I encountered the same problem.  The fix for me to was to review the application history log in Windows -> Adminsitrative Tools to see what the specific error was and I found that it needed a child service to be started that wasn't

Hope that helps.